# jqGrid does not refresh after post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

**The idea**: I load my data in jqGrid. The user can select multiple rows and import them by clicking on the store button. The data is stored on the server
and the state column is modified. After posting the jqGrid is actualized.

**The problem**: After posting to server, the page is refreshed and jqGrid refreshs (it calls GetData method) but the grid shows no rows anymore.

View part:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "MyData", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" name="dataRow" id="dataRow" />
    <button id="storeSelected" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="StoreSelected" class="btn btn-default">Store Selected</button>
}

<table id="importGrid"></table>
<div id="importPager"></div>
```

Scripts part:

```
var lastsel;
var configUrl = '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyData")';
var editUrl = '@Url.Action("UpdateData", "MyData")';
jQuery("#importGrid").jqGrid({
        url: configUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        editurl: editUrl,
        colNames: ['Import State', 'Start', 'End', 'Description'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'ImportState', index: 'ImportState', width: 40, sortable: true },
            { name: 'Start', index: 'Start', formatter: 'date' },
            { name: 'End', index: 'End', formatter: 'date' },
            { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 150, sortable: false, editable: true },
        onSelectRow: function(id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery("#importGrid").jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel, false);
                jQuery('#importGrid').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                lastsel = id;
            }
        },
        ...
});

$('#storeSelected').click(function() {

       var multiplerowdata = jQuery("#importGrid").getGridParam('selarrrow');
        $('#dataRow').val(multiplerowdata);           
});
```

Controller part:

```
public ActionResult Import(
        MyViewModel viewModel,
        string datarow,
        string submitButton)
{
  if (submitButton == "StoreSelected")
  {
     ... // Does the import
  }
}

public ActionResult GetData()
{
   return Json(_Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two nights I finally found the bug! Everything is alright with jqGrid. The problem was that I imported
the data to my database via my O/R Mapper and that confused jqGrid
while refreshing.

So this will be a lesson for me to always use properly ViewModels, also
when the Entity seems to be quite simple. Hope this helps one time to somebody else.